# Unexpected Argument

Tags: mysql, sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -E -S localhost\ACTUAL -Q RESTORE DATABASE [Kronos0001] FROM DISK='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\backup\Kronos0001_2_1_67_RTM.bak' WITH FILE = 1, RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 10, MOVE 'Kronos0001' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.ACTUAL\MSSQL\DATA\Kronos0001_Data.mdf', MOVE 'Kronos0001_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.ACTUAL\MSSQL\DATA\Kronos0001_Log.ldf
```

Drops me back unexpected argument

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Does sqlcmd work with MySQL?

Comment: There is a `'` missing at the end, is something else missing?

Comment: From the command , it seems like you should tag this as SQL Server, not mysql. If that is true, take a look at this: https://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/. Also, use quotation marks around the query: ... -Q "RESTORE..."